# Getting the most recent date after using group by with mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like the sample below. I need to retrieve the most recent date for a specified user.

```
id sender_id receiver_id content date               
-- --------- ----------- ------- ----               
1  5         7           test    2013-03-13 10:33:54
2  13        7           test 2  2012-03-13 12:01:36
3  5         7           test 3  2013-01-05 09:15:37
4  13        7           test 4  2013-04-05 08:17:39
```

My current SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE receiver_id=7 group by sender_id
```

I would expect the result set to include just two entries with the most recent date for each like this:

```
4  13        7           test 4  2013-04-05 08:17:39
1  5         7           test    2013-03-13 10:33:54
```

Do I need to do some sort of sub select to first get the most recent date?

Comment: Have you tried `ORDER BY date DESC`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select most recent results based on composite of fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817204/select-most-recent-results-based-on-composite-of-fields)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are grouping by `sender_id` but returning all columns. The value of non-aggregated rows could be underemined and not affected by an order by.

You could use a query like this to get the results that you need:

```
SELECT *
FROM   messages
WHERE  (sender_id, receiver_id, date) IN (
          SELECT   sender_id, receiver_id, MAX(date)
          FROM     messages
          WHERE    receiver_id=7
          GROUP BY sender_id, receiver_id)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84ff0/8).

Comment: That works but how do I filter a specific receiver_id?  (e.g. WHERE receiver_id = 7)

Comment: @Paul please see my updated answer. This will return the last message of every sender_id that has receiver_id=7

Comment: it's working but pegging my CPU for over a minute now...my current table has about 300k rows total and maybe 30 rows for receiver_id 7

Comment: @Paul if you try to execute only the subquery, is it still that slow? if it is, you should probably add an index on (sender_id, receiver_id)

Comment: The sub query is working great, and actually this is returning the data I need. Thanks!